# NServiceBus SQL Server Transport and SQL Persistence on different databases

Tags: sql-server, persistence, nservicebus, transport

I'm trying to run a NServiceBus Host application using SQL Server Transport and SQL Persistence. When I point both the transport and persistence connection strings to the same database everything works fine. However when I point them to separate databases, the program crashes upon receiving its first message, throwing this exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'persistence.MyService_MySaga'.`

Here is my endpoint configuration:

```
var persistenceConnection = @"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Database=MyServicePersistence;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=100;";
var transportConnection = @"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Database=MyServiceTransport;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=100;";

var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("MyService");
endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
transport.ConnectionString(transportConnection);
transport.UseSchemaForQueue("error", "dbo");
transport.UseSchemaForQueue("audit", "dbo");
transport.Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.SendsAtomicWithReceive);

var persistence = endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<SqlPersistence>();
persistence.SqlVariant(SqlVariant.MsSqlServer);
persistence.ConnectionBuilder(() => new SqlConnection(persistenceConnection));
persistence.Schema("persistence");

var subscriptions = persistence.SubscriptionSettings();
subscriptions.CacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

*Potentially noteworthy:* I can prevent the exception from being thrown if I change the `TransportTransactionMode` from `SendsAtomicWithReceive` to `None`. However I don't want to do that because it causes all failed messages to go directly to the error queue, bypassing all retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you discovered a bug in our implementation, thanks for raising it.

I created an issue in the SQL persistence repo, you can track it [there](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql/issues/144).

Most likely we'll release the fix in the new upcoming major, hope that works for you. Can you indicate how urgent the problem is?

Comment: Actually, I just found out that someone else from our team has already been in contact with someone else from Particular (Simon I believe?) about this very issue. As far as urgency goes, I wouldn't say it's extremely urgent since there are workarounds. However, the workarounds aren't exactly desirable for our situation.